# How to find groups in data, characterized by the most different behavior in alcohol consumption?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dataset, descriptive-statistics, group-differences

I've got a question concerning the [Student Alcohol Consumption dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/STUDENT%20ALCOHOL%20CONSUMPTION) from the UCI Repository.

Please, help me understand which methods or models, preferably using Python and sklearn , to use to find **typical groups of students, characterized by the most different behavior in alcohol consumption**? Also, how can one substantiate these groups and behavior?

I think that some clustering methods can solve this problem, but don't know which one to use.

Comment: Have a look at [Gaussian Mixture Models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html).